# FIREFOX Mac asking to save PHP not loading HTML

Tags: php, html, firefox, redirect

I am going mad over this crazy issue. I have a lab with 3 macs and 5 windows servers. I have a PHP application that i developed that has been working FAB on Firefox on mac for weeks. In the past few days my Mac Firefox on the Imac and Mac mini are now asking to SAVE PHP files and not redirect to them from a header(Location: ) statement in my code. My Mac Laptop works fine.!!!! so does Firefox on every windows computer i can lay my hands on, laptops , PCS, servers. Safari, Chrome all work fine on ALL the macs and PCs ... I have a WAMP server set up on 2 servers , exactly the same PHP code, exactly the same WAMP and both fail on the Imac and Mac Mini... keep asking to save the PHP.. I have downgraded to earlier versions of Firefox on both computers and it is still asking to save the file. I have tried deleting the profile, created a new FFox profile, deleted the Mimetypes file etc etc - but nothing i try seems to fix the situation on the two macs. I am running v 45.0 on both macs , auto updated.

Comment: Nothing to do with the browser. The webserver isn't configured properly.

Comment: Have you tried opening only  `http://localhost` ?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the feedback - opening localhost would mean i would have to have the server running on my Mac, Localhost on the wamp server was working fine.

Comment: Fixed - I finally resorted to installing WAMP 2.5 64bit on one of the servers and hey presto the Mac computers were happy again. I was running 2.4 x86 before and i think that apache became corrupt somehow, no amount of restarts would fix it. Also i modified my code so that the header(Location) redirection was moved into the PHP function and not after the function had executed in the code. This i think has helped potentially as well.  I think Ceejayoz was on the right track, although all other PHP were working fine (about 150 of them) it was only one redirection that was broken so who knows. ta